# What do you call a graph where all nodes are reachable?

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

simple question.

What's the term for an (undirected) graph, where one can reach any other node from any node?

Comment: I'm confused. One of the tags you attached answers your question.

Comment: I believe the answer is simple `connected graph` :)

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me do this in a proper answer folks.

Yes, it's a `connected graph` - a graph that for any two given nodes, has a path between them.

*But It's a confusing name. Is anyone else annoyed by confusing names in maths? Not that we can do anything about it, this far.*

Comment: Why do you think it's confusing?

Comment: If it wasn't connected it wouldn't be a graph. There's a thin line between just a set of nodes and not-connected graph.

Comment: Do any two compatible disjoint graphs form a one graph implicitly?